# nested if statement gets skipped in foreach statement

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to make a blog. I have two models with a one to many relation, Messages and Comments where by Messages can have multiple Comments.
Now I am trying to get only the comments that belong to a certain message.If you make a comment to a message the value of the messageId gets passed to ComToMes inside the comments Model. With the if statement I want to check if the ComToMes is equal to messageId if so the comment belongs to that certain message and should be displayed. The problem is that if I try it in the debugger with some breakpoints the if stament gets skipped like if it didnt exist.

I have looked arround and have seen some work arrounds with for example using a text tag inside the if statement but that doesnt seem to work with me.

**Here is my View**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-10">
    @*Places al the comments and decodes the html from the ckeditor*@
    @foreach (var message in Model)
    {
       foreach (var comments in message.Comments)
       {
          if (comments.ComToMes == message.MessagesId)
          {
              <div class="well" id="CommentBox">
                 <h7>@comments.WhenCreated</h7>                                                    
        @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(comments.Comments_body))
             </div>
         }
         else if(comments == null)
         {
             <h2>Be the first to comment</h2>
         }

      }
   }
  </div>
</div>
```

**edit 1**
After some more research I have found out that the nested for each statement is not evaluated

Comment: Does the `else if` statement evaluate?

Comment: no it doesnt get evaluated the whole if statement isnt

Comment: @Kapobajza It looks like the nested for each statement not even gets evalueted

Comment: @ruinerwarrior Can you post your model code.

Comment: @ruinerwarrior Does the `Model` and  `message.Comments` collection has elements or are they empty? If there are elements but still it skips the code, try removing all temporary internet and .net symbol files, clean & rebuild the solution and try again.

Comment: It would be neater if you pass the messageId to your business model and query your comments on the server, sending to your client just a collection of those comments associated to your messageId. Getting all comments and iterating through them to see if you have to show each one of them could become quite resource consuming if your site grows.

Comment: @SivaGopal both models have elements but i can try to remove all the temporary files

Comment: @Bardo That is a nice suggestion but I am very new to asp.net so that is why I have taken this simple approach. Could you show a example of how I could do that, or a source where I can see a example?

Comment: @ruinerwarrior I'll do something better and faster, if you don't know it, check NerdDinner tutorial. Probably the best and most complete tutorial for ASP.NET MVC beginners: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/introducing-the-nerddinner-tutorial